# array manipulation into new array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an messed up array which coming from else where:

```
["person: John, Comment:, id_number:1, he is a guitar player","person: James, Comment:, id_number:38, James remark goes here"]
```

how can I make it into this

```
[
{name:"John",id_number:1,Comment:"he is a guitar player"},
{name:"James",id_number:38,Comment:"James remark goes here"}
]
```

Comment: The best option will be to get the input corrected, than manipulating the wrong input.

Comment: You don't have quoted strings, this would be excessively hard. Fix it at source

Comment: @rahul I have no control over the API

Comment: @PaulS. the source is coming from other API which I can't control at all.

Comment: Tell the person who owns that API that their API is broken. Get coffee.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
var arr = ["person: John, Comment:, id_number:1, he is a guitar player","person: James, Comment:, id_number:38, James remark goes here"];
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var thisPart = arr[i].split(',');
    newArr.push(
        {
            name:thisPart[0].replace('person: ',''),
            id_number:thisPart[2].replace(' id_number:',''),
            Comment:$.trim(thisPart[3])
        }
    );
};
console.log(newArr);
```

You could get fancier and try to search out the values you want, if they're not always in the right order.

Here it is working: http://codepen.io/caleboleary/pen/bENGbx

Good luck!

Comment: I tried the same thing, http://pastebin.com/pmMizXZ5 but why I got the same result for every object?

Comment: I took a look at the code you tried, I think mostly what you're missing is splitting each string in 'obj' by ',' so when you perform your ':' split you're only getting the 'person' and not any of the other data, because that's lost when you create your splitted variable. Does that make sense? It's because the array objects you're receiving from the API aren't actually arrays, just strings with commas in them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could transform the data with `.map` and a *RegExp*

```
["person: John, Comment:, id_number:1, he is a guitar player","person: James, Comment:, id_number:38, James remark goes here"].map(e => {
    var m = e.match(/^person: ([^,]+), Comment:, id_number:([^,]+), (.*)$/);
    return {"person": m[1], "id_number": +m[2], "Comment": m[3]};
});
// [
//    {"person": "John", "id_number": 1, "Comment": "he is a guitar player"},
//    {"person": "James", "id_number": 38, "Comment": "James remark goes here"}
// ]
```

I can't guarantee this would work with all outputs of the API as it is generating bad output, really the fix should be at source

### Contact the API owner